# Is there away to map apex classes/triggers to their test classes?

Tags: reporting, code-coverage, metadata

I have a requirement to map the test classes in my companies org to the classes and triggers that they test. We have a big org with over a thousand classes, so doing this by hand is not how I want to spend the next few months. Is there any tools or methods inside the Salesforce platform that will allow me to automate this or at least some part of this.

Answer (score 4):

There's no "report" for this, but you can use the [ApexCodeCoverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexcodecoverage.htm) to retrieve the tests and methods that cover a particular class or trigger.

Traditionally, I've always named the tests after the class they test, such as:

```
SomePageController
SomePageControllerTest
SomeTriggerHandler
SomeTriggerHandlerTest
... etc ...
```

Since there's no automated tool, you are going to have to spend some time initially or run a query with the Tooling API. In theory, you could do this with some spreadsheet work to minimize the amount of manual effort you need.

Comment: You could automate this by creating a batch over the [`ApexClass`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm) object.  [`ApexTrigger`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apextrigger.htm) is also accessible via SOQL.

Comment: Many versions ago, up unit v28.0 you could include unit test directly in the Class they tested. With an Org as mature as yours, that might be another thing you have to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

There is an idea for it.Please vote it.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kPRmAAM